# In "Southpaw“, why didn't they do gunpowder residue (GSR) tests on everybody in the hallway?

Tags: plot-explanation, southpaw

In [*Southpaw*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southpaw_(film)) (2015), only one person fired a gun in that room. Surely it would be simple to test everyone to find the shooter, even without the gun.

Why didn't they do gunpowder residue (GSR) tests on everybody in the hallway?

Comment: I fail to see why this has attracted an opinion-based close vote. There are very clear and practical reasons why GSR testing wouldn't be useful here, in the same way that we can rule out why the police didn't bring in a psychic or use an [Electrolite Neutron-Magnentic Test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SHhxZ4BWeBQ)

Answer (score 13):

Not including the man seen holding the gun and the actual shooter, there are a dozen celebrities with their security staff, many of whom have likely fired guns at the range within the last 1-2 days, or cleaned guns even if they've not been fired. After the gun is fired, the putative shooter is then manhandled to the ground by several security staff and his gun taken off him and handled by various other people. All of these people will now have gunshot residues on their hands and clothes despite that not being the gun that was used in the shooting.

As you can see from the quote below from the Texas DA, gunshot residue testing is pretty useless at detecting *when* a gun was fired and is used most often in disproving someone's account of events, particularly where that person didn't introduce the gun into the crime scene (e.g. *"No, officer, I've never handled a gun in my life"*, etc).

> **What can GSR analysis do for you?**
>
> The strength of a GSR test comes from its ability to associate an individual with a firearm discharge **when that person has not otherwise been associated with a weapon...**
>
> <sub><sup>[The Texas Prosecutor: Gunshot residue: Not the smoking gun TV makes it out to be](https://www.tdcaa.com/journal/gunshot-residue-not-the-smoking-gun-tv-makes-it-out-to-be/)</sup></sub>

A GSR test would be next-to-useless in this situation. It would find a dozen people in that room had gunshot residue on their hands and under those circumstances, the District Attorney would much rather the detectives *hadn't* run a GSR test because it would introduce massive amounts of reasonable doubt into any future prosecution, even if the actual shooter is eventually identified through other means, such as CCTV or a witness statement.