Why are guns left at the murder scenes in "The Godfather"?
In the movie "The Godfather", the Corleone family go to great lengths to make sure that the gun is left on the crime scene at least twice:

At the killing of Paulie in the car outside New York ("Leave the gun! Take the cannoli!")
When they assault McCluskey and Sollozzo in the restaurant ("He told me a million times")

Why is it so important to leave the gun on scene (and the movie to show this)?

I expect that the gun has been stolen. Paulie's body will be found in a stolen car with a stolen gun.

@SimonCrase So what if it is? It's not like they're trying to frame anyone else for the murder. Unclear why the gun being stolen would have any bearing at all, they'd leave it behind no matter where it came from.

@SimonCrase Precisely, finding a stolen gun at the murder scene gives the police no lead at all... which is exactly what they'd have if they found no gun at all. It's important to not leave a gun that you own, but there's no additional benefit to specifically leaving a stolen gun. If the gun is stolen, it doesn't really matter whether they leave it or not, as it's not leading back to them anyway. It wouldn't explain why it's very important to leave the gun behind.

@NuclearHoagie "finding a stolen gun at the murder scene gives the police no lead at all...". Yes, that is what I said. I'm glad you figured that out finally for yourself.

@SimonCrase And what you're saying makes no sense. You're saying it is very important that the mobsters leave the gun behind... because it doesn't matter whether they do or not?

@NuclearHoagie "You're saying it is very important..." No: the words "very important" are something you said. Your logical fallacy is strawman

This is addressed in the film's source novel. In brief, getting caught with a recently-fired gun is extremely difficult to explain to the police. Better to dump the gun and risk the very slim chance that they can match a fingerprint.

Sonny broke in curtly, “It has to be Mike. For a million different
reasons. Most important they got him down as faggy. And he can do the
job, I guarantee that, and that’s important because this is the only
shot we’ll get at that sneaky bastard Turk. So now we have to figure
out the best way to back him up. Tom, Clemenza, Tessio, find out where
Sollozzo will take him for the conference, I don’t care how much it
costs. When we find that out we can figure out how we can get a weapon
into his hands. Clemenza, I want you to get him a really ‘safe’ gun
out of your collection, the ‘coldest’ one you got. Impossible to
trace. Try to make it short barrel with a lot of blasting power. It
doesn’t have to be accurate. He’ll be right on top of them when he
uses it. Mike, as soon as you’ve used the gun, drop it on the floor.
Don’t be caught with it on you. Clemenza, tape the barrel and the
trigger with that special stuff you got so he won’t leave prints.
Remember, Mike, we can square everything, witnesses, and so forth, but
if they catch you with the gun on you we can’t square that.


You can't be caught with a gun (recently fired or not) that can be identified as a murder weapon. Because there are ballistics methods to determine which gun killed who:

As with fingerprints, every firearm has unique characteristics. The barrel of a weapon leaves distinct markings on a projectile. The breech mechanism also leaves distinct markings on the cartridge case. These markings are produced by the breech face itself, the firing pin, extractor, and ejector. Firearms examiners are able to examine bullets and cartridge casings to determine if they were expelled from the same firearm. Automated Firearms Ballistics Technology

That's why any buttonman knows the risks and will not take a chance keeping a "hot" gun. If they don't have a gun when frisked/arrested, then, there's less risks at being forced into a Gonzalez test for gunshot residue. Being caught with such a weapon would make you the perpetrator of the felony.
In many books/movies, you see policemen identifying guns and their background, every shooting/robbery/murder they have been used for before.

Forensic weapon examination was still very much in its infancy in the 1940s, but if the shooter was unlucky, a bullet might be matched to a specific weapon; https://nij.ojp.gov/nij-hosted-online-training-courses/firearms-examiner-training/module-02/1921-1924. Much more dangerous (to the shooter) would simply be the policeman smelling the chamber and recognising that the gun had been fired recently. That, along with circumstantial evidence would usually be enough to secure a conviction.

A GSR test would be useless if a suspect was found in possession of a gun. Regardless of whether they'd fired that particular weapon, they would be covered with the residue of previous firings, as would anyone else who had handled that gun.

This answer may be of interest to you; https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/122373/in-southpaw-why-didnt-they-do-gunpowder-residue-gsr-tests-on-everybody-in

@Valorum Science doesn't have to be perfect if the police thinks you did it (which they do). The expert just needs to say "it matches", even if he only checked that it's the same caliber. The police statement and motive will do the rest.
